# $\rho(A \circ A) \ge \rho(A)^2.$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a nonnegative matrix $A$. Can we claim the following:
$$\rho(A \circ A) \ge \rho(A)^2.$$ Here $A \circ A$ is the Hadamard product.

Context: For a nonnegative matrix $A$ I know the spectral radius. Can we use that to give a bound for the spectral radius of $A \circ A$.

I computationally verified for a few examples. It seems to be true.

Comment: Could you please provide some context? What reason do you have to believe that this claim is correct?

Answer (score 3):

If $ \rho(A)$ denotes the spectral radius, then no. Take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 \\ 2 &1 \end{bmatrix}.$ Then we have

$\rho(A)^2=9$ and $\rho(A \circ A)=5.$

Comment: Can we say something if we have zeros on the main diagonal?

Answer (score 1):

The *reversed* inequality is true. Note that $A\circ A$ is a principal submatrix of $A\otimes A$. If we embed $A\circ A$ inside a zero matrix of the same size as $A\otimes A$, we can view $A\circ A$ as a nonnegative matrix $B$ that is entrywise bounded above by $A\otimes A$. It follows that $B^k\le(A\otimes A)^k$ and hence $\|B^k\|^{1/k}\le\|(A\otimes A)^k\|^{1/k}$ using Frobenius norm or the induced maximum norm. Therefore, by Gelfand's formula, we always have $\rho(A\circ A)=\rho(B)\color{red}{\le}\rho(A\otimes A)=\rho(A)^2$.